# Async/Await not working when calling the web API

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, async-await

Hi I have this Asynchronous Web API, I think when I execute this in a button click, the rest of the processes won't continue until the API returns the results, Below is my API,

```
btnSubmit.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        var jobId = txtJobID.Text;

        if (txtJobID.Text.Length <= 0)
        {
            txtJobID.RequestFocus();
            txtJobID.SetError("Job ID required", iconError);
        }
        else
        {
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://192.168.79.174:90/api/test/" + jobId));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";




            using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
            {

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    dynamic arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

                    foreach (dynamic obj in arr)
                    {
                        tvJobID.Text = obj.JobID;
                        tvJobType.Text = obj.JobType;
                        tvDueDate.Text = obj.DueDate;
                        tvVisitTime.Text = obj.Time;
                        tvVisitStatus.Text = obj.VisitStatus;
                        tvAddress1.Text = obj.Address1;
                        tvAddress2.Text = obj.Address2;
                        tvPostCode.Text = obj.PostCode;
                        tvAuthority.Text = obj.Authority;
                    }

                    if (content == null || content == "" || content == "[]")
                    {

                        //Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");

                        Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "Invalid Job ID or no visits for this ID. Please try again", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        layoutController.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };
```

When I debug the code, Specially where the foreach statement is, it takes quite a bit of time for API to return results. What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: How long is _quite a bit of time_? What time frame do you expect? Have you profiled the web service to find any bottle neck if one should exist? Why the use of `dynamic`? It seems very unlikely you truly don't know the type of object your web service will return until runtime.

Comment: @JSteward the app freeze for like 7-8 seconds. I can't see any bottle necks, I think I'm using the async/await on wrong places. can I use await on any other place. Sorry I have a very little understanding on this. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using the `HttpWebRequest` use the `HttpClient`. It has a very easy to use `async` api. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)